# Style google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have the fowlling Google Map created with my own icon. The code is the fowlling:

https://paste.ee/p/O3U44

However I want ot add the style Silver, however I'm not sure how to modify this code.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you want to add silver style in RHP image?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I want to add the style in the map itself - I already add the costum pin as you saw it. I just need to add the Silver style.

Comment: This link will be useful to you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling  and this https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/.

Comment: Hi. I've been there. And on the second link I can create the map, however, I get the code but I'm unsure where I can put it - here is am exampel of the code that I get: https://gyazo.com/5add3b137a4d6b1230b762b62a50acda

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: My answer is working well for you or not?

Comment: Yes it did! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this code.

**Here you need to add your google api key in below link.**

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=Your_api_key&callback=initMap"
```

Here is the code.

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.769671, -9.097975),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
          styles : [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
        });
        
 
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: 'https://novo2.rhp.pt/map.png'
          }
        };
 
        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.769671, -9.097975),
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];
 
        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map,
            content:'<div>Test</div>'
            
          });
        });
      }
```

```css
 /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

**If you wanted to still changes map style then follow this link https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and create whatever you want and just copy whole JSON code and replace in above `styles`object.**

Hope this helps.